# Magento: main menu items not getting translated

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've installed a magento store with a swedish language pack. The problem is that when I change the language, the core menu items (such as Log in, My account, My Wishlist in top menu) do not get translated. If I change locale in System->Configuration->General->Locale Options to Swedish, then the same menu items are always in swedish disregarding the change to English language.

I searched through the web - I found a lot of articles on languages in magento, but can't find this kind of problem.

Please, help.

P.S. I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 community edition

Comment: You have to change the locale in store view level! Go to system->configuration->general->locale and select from the top left drop down your Swedish store view. Then change the locale to Swedish to apply the language only in this store.

Comment: Oh my GOD. Thank you so much. Still can't get accustomed to the fact that different language is a different store.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly before choosing your locale options you must select from dropdown the right store present in the top left corner then you can change the locale as Swedish.
If problem still persists try downloading a proper language translator pack because the one you downloaded might not have the translations for the fields you want like the menu options

Answer (score 0):

Go To your menu and select your store from left upper side and write translated name that you want to set for perticular store and save and clear cache. it's simple done bro.